# Flutter Build size increased after updating minSdkVersion to 23

Tags: android, apk, flutter-build, android-min-sdk, flutter3.7

[image]After I updated Flutter to 3.7, the Build size increased after updating minSdkVersion to 23
in the flutter new project, when I updated minSdkVersion from 21 to 23, I faced that the Apk size increased from 17mg to 37 mg.

I don't know why? And is it normal?

Comment: You can simply inspect the generated APK files yourself and see what have increased in size. Just open the APK files with a ZIP tool. Android Studio also has the ability to analyze APK files and show their contained failed/folders and size. BTW: Please do not post screen shots of text files like build.gradle. If you want to show something from within that file paste the text content (e.g. relevant section) into your question and format it as code.